# KDB+ / Q Table creation with dynamic number of columns

Tags: list, kdb, q-lang

I am doing stuff like this:

```
q)seed:5
q)numvals:3
q)id:`u#1+til seed;
q)vals:numvals cut (seed*numvals)?`8
q)1!([]id;vals)
```

Now I am getting a table like this:

```
id| vals                      
--| --------------------------
1 | bhlkdkfd ghmjjepm gphfcddd
2 | jnloahej ipbcbnop heokehhg
3 | eijocfod nbbeopjo ddhiffmp
4 | cndelncn cmcmkckd aelpmccp
5 | nhjdlned cbkgpggg kgbcifbj
```

**Is there a way to automatically unfold the `vals` list during the table generation to create a table that looks like this:**

```
id| vals0    vals1    vals2              
--| --------------------------
1 | bhlkdkfd ghmjjepm gphfcddd
2 | jnloahej ipbcbnop heokehhg
3 | eijocfod nbbeopjo ddhiffmp
4 | cndelncn cmcmkckd aelpmccp
5 | nhjdlned cbkgpggg kgbcifbj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is a dictionary from a dictionary of symbol keys to a list of equal length vectors. Dynamically create the column names using "string til".

```
q){ `id xkey update id:i from flip (`$"vals",/:string til y)!(y#x)?\:`8 }[3;4]
id| vals0    vals1    vals2    vals3
--| -----------------------------------
0 | lkamnmmm nfnbfmkm kiblpojl onhlghno
1 | ehippdmm pocmhfkf edmeodcp iajdgbcc
2 | kcbjofjk ammebbah dajdafek aafdkpao

q){ `id xkey update id:i from flip (`$"vals",/:string til y)!(y#x)?\:`8 }[3;6]
id| vals0    vals1    vals2    vals3    vals4    vals5
--| -----------------------------------------------------
0 | hkdnolgf jbfokhef medkopgk objjkcmf hcnelcjh mkmiagdh
1 | kagnelcp lhjkpjen gokacegn iiocipck gpeachbd apmdghdl
2 | bejncmmp mfhnonen klihfepf oieoflli bbgombmk dkbnlhmd
```

Your key id column probably isn't necessary, kdb tables have a virtual i column that is the row number. Here I use an update to make it visible.

To explain this code step by step, start from the right and try evaluating each part.

A. In kdb we can call a function with two arguments like so: (x is 3, y is 4)

```
q){x+y}[3;4]
7
```

B. The question mark in kdb can be used for a lot of things, When it has a number on the left and a `8 on the right it generates n random symbols of length 8. Here I use the : adverb to modify the function and call it multiple times for-each item on the left:

```
q){(y#x)}[3;4]
3 3 3 3
q){(y#x)?\:`8}[3;4]
gknafbmp odolnkpd pblgicmp
aphcdfab mgidjeap iledgchk
ppinbcgh kcijdnbg jleeoccb
ljjdnami affhgjlm cnijgipc
```

C.Generate the column names by concatenating strings and again using an adverb:

```
q){(`$"vals",/:string til y)}[3;10]
`vals0`vals1`vals2`vals3`vals4`vals5`vals6`vals7`vals8`vals9
```

D. A table in kdb is a flipped dictionary. A simple example:

```
q)d:`a`b!(1 2 3;4 5 6)
q)d
a| 1 2 3
b| 4 5 6
q)flip d
a b
---
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

I use that technique to generate my table:

```
q){(`$"vals",/:string til y)!(y#x)?\:`8 }[3;5]
vals0| djgndbde hlggaadm pbofgnac
vals1| goppgmfe jlfpmlab ibgkihem
vals2| npklikob okkmmlbi llnbhgha
vals3| lbekogce kjclledc cdjbmdpm
vals4| okmleidn lebjkagh cenblgbi
q){flip (`$"vals",/:string til y)!(y#x)?\:`8 }[3;5]
vals0    vals1    vals2    vals3    vals4
--------------------------------------------
iiifjhhi idinahfa iejibpcl hebikhmc cjlegpke
jicockjo kpjphpof kfimnmgh fpjolkmb mkkjldfc
acjfnnpd ciflaggo ennfgapg bbodkdla bichmhpj
```

E. Finally update using the virtual i column and use xkey to make it a keyed table:

```
q){ `id xkey update id:i from flip (`$"vals",/:string til y)!(y#x)?\:`8 }[3;4]
id| vals0    vals1    vals2    vals3
--| -----------------------------------
0 | mkfcpkdg dnhmifmf gedbdmkb dpdcdhib
1 | efhafoeh jpidfdno fdbddhgn fimolnmb
2 | jjmeickp clkbenoe lndodeel pgbfojdb
```

I advise using this technique to break down any kdb code to try and understand it. Work from right to left, querying the smallest part you don't understand...until you do.

Comment: Puuh.. thanks for that! it Works, but puuuuuh.. Would you mind explaining it a little bit. Like read the line what happens?

Comment: Just added some more questios.. those are related to this one. Thats why i am adding it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559343/kdb-q-syntax-for-gods)

Comment: Ah one more thing regarding this table. The virtual i index, is it persistent, i mean if i reorder the table, will that index be still usable as primary key?